# regex for grep for screen resolution of the form 1280x720

Tags: regex, bash

I am trying to give grep a regex pattern for screen resolution(e.g. `1280x720`) as following

```
[0-9]{3,}x[0-9]{3,}
```

but it doesn't seem to be working.

The following works but that doesn't translate to the above one.

```
[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]*x[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]*
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your regex seems fine for bash :

```
[[ 1280x720 =~ [0-9]{3,}x[0-9]{3,} ]] && echo OK
OK
```

If you want to use `grep` :

```
$ cat B
640x480
$
$ grep -c "[0-9]\{3,\}x[0-9]\{3,\}" B
1
$
$ grep --version
grep (GNU grep) 2.14
```

Comment: What am I doing wrong here ?

$ cat B
640x480
1280x720

$ grep -c [0-9]\{3,\}x[0-9]\{3,\} B
0

$ grep -c "[0-9]{3,}x[0-9]{3,}" B
0

Comment: Thanks ! I was missing quotes there. `grep -o "[0-9]\{3,\}x[0-9]\{3,\}" -c` worked.

Answer (score 3):

That is an ERE (extended regular expression), grep uses BREs (basic regular expressions by default. You can either escape the {}:

```
grep '[0-9]\{3,\}x[0-9]\{3,\}'
```

or tell grep to interpret it as an ERE:

```
grep -E '[0-9]{3,}x[0-9]{3,}'
```